# A.split(B) where a and b are audio files

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, split, gtts

To split a string object by another string we have the `split` method. `'this is an example'.split('i')` results in `['th', 's ', 's an example']`. How to do the same with audio files? I mean if I had

```
A = audio1.mp3
B = audio2.mp3

A.split(B)
```

I want an array of audio parts of A split by B. In my case I have used gTTs to get audio files.

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on the library that's giving you `audio1` and `audio2`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have used gTTs to get audio files.

Comment: Then I'd take a look at the docs for the objects they're working with to see if they have a relevant method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe gTTs is an unofficial client of google TTS engine. it passes a string to the google TTS server and writes the byte stream to a file like audio.mp3